# How to save values selected from a flutter multiselect widget in to a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used this flutter package "multiselect" in my flutter project to select multiple data from a dropdown.

```
List _fines;

MultiSelect(
            autovalidate: false,
            titleText: "Fine list",
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null) {
                return 'Please select one or more option(s)';
              }
            },
            errorText: 'Please select one or more option(s)',
            dataSource: [
              {"display": "Fine No 1", "index": 1, "value": 5000},
              {"display": "Fine no 2", "index": 2, "value": 2500},
              {"display": "Fine no 3", "index": 3, "value": 1000},
              {"display": "Fine no 4", "index": 4, "value": 500}
            ],
            textField: 'display',
            valueField: 'index',
            filterable: true,
            required: true,
            value: null,
            onSaved: (value) {
              setState(() {
                  _fines = value;
                });

            })
```

I cannot save data into the list. After the on saved it says _fines list is null. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can get your last selected values with `change` callback function as a parameter of `MultiSelect` widget

```
List<int> selectedValues = [];

MultiSelect(
            autovalidate: false,
            titleText: "title",
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null) {
                return 'Please select one or more option(s)';
              }
            },
            errorText: 'Please select one or more option(s)',
            dataSource: [
              {
                "display": "Australia",
                "value": 1,
              },
              {
                "display": "Canada",
                "value": 2,
              },
              {
                "display": "India",
                "value": 3,
              },
              {
                "display": "United States",
                "value": 4,
              }
            ],
            textField: 'display',
            valueField: 'value',
            filterable: true,
            required: true,
            value: null,
            change: (values){
              selectedValues = values;
              print(selectedValues);
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it doesn't work for me. Still getting null.

Comment: I tested it and it worked well for me.
Please check if you use the last version of a library in your pubspec.yaml `flutter_multiselect: 0.4.0`
If you have the correct version, please do `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` again and if it still wouldn't work, then can you share the output of `flutter doctor -v` and add code of the widget that use `MultiSelect`?